# How to Make Glossy Colors in CSS.

Tags: css, colors

I want to make Gold Glossy Color Background using Gold and Silver colors. I don't know how to make that..
I have made Gradient and i can make only gradient. Can anyone please help me to make Gold Glossy Color.. Or any color with Gloss Effects as we can make images in Photoshop with Glossy effect..
I want to make Glossy Background colors in CSS..

Comment: CSS can't do this. You are looking for `svg` filter, if want a real Glossy effect.

Comment: post a screenshot of the kind of color you want to achieve.

Comment: what background colors you want, again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a CSS gradient inside the CSS file. This is how.

You can use the CSS command

```
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
```

If you want a genarator to do that for you, I am using this
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Or you can create one on your own.

When you generate the CSS code that runs pretty much in most browsers nowtimes you can then copy paste it into your CSS style and have gradient graphics on the spot avoiding generating images.

I hope that helped.

Comment: Perhaps the editor was being slightly obtuse when he stated the question was unclear.  It seems obvious that what was needed was a shiny (think chrome, the metal, not the browser, or gold) background color.  Never tried, but I suspect a reasonable result might be achieved using box-shadow with insets.